# I am stuck in my while loop with elapsed time of a timer as condition

Tags: c#, while-loop, timer

I am starting a timer and I want the method to wait until some time passed. I have searched in other similar questions but cannot find a clear answer.
Why is does the following code freeze the app?
elapsed time starts at 0 and intervall is 1000 (1sec)

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        elapsedtime2++;
    }

//this is inside my method
timer2.Start();
while (elapsedtime2 < 3)
    {

    }
timer2.Stop();
```

Comment: You don't have any locking around the access to `elapsedTime2`, and yet it's read/written by multiple threads. The runtime is perfectly within its rights to remove the reads of `elapsedtime2` in the `elapsedtime2 < 2` check, which means your loop turns into an infinite one

Comment: (+1) Thank you for this comment. I am trying to learn and this is the constructive criticisime i was looking for. Now I know what is going wrong. I will be looking into access locking and when/how/why reads can be removed at runtime.

Comment: @canton7 can you give a reference or something? I had no clue that the runtime could do such thing: `remove the reads`.

Comment: @rytisk I don't have one to hand, but it's a common feature of many languages that the compiler/runtime (and even the CPU) is allowed to reorder reads/writes such that the effects of the reordering aren't visible to the *current thread*. This is e.g. why `volatile` exists in C. In .NET, it's the JIT which does this, although not as much as some other languages.

Comment: @rytisk: See for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41634395/8248570 Quote: "The C# compiler and CLR jitter are permitted to make a great many optimizations that assume that the current thread is the only thread running."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to pause execution for a second is:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

If you're familiar with async/await, the async equivalent is:

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` this worked well. Are there any restrictions to this method though? Any situations I should not use these.

Comment: It's normal indicative of some other problem, but there's nothing wrong with it in itself. Of course your thread becomes unresponsive during this time, so if it's a UI thread for example, your UI is going to freeze

Comment: I would mention `Task.Delay` before than `Thread.Sleep`, since it would probably be better suited if writing a UI, as seem to be the case here.

Comment: @JonasH I don't see any mention that this is a UI application? If OP hasn't had a proper introduction to async/await, throwing it at them won't be helpful. Since they don't know about Thread.Sleep I was assuming that they probably wouldn't be familiar with async/await

Answer (score 0):

You can use events to get the desired behaviour:

```
private int elapsedtime2 = 0;
private ManualResetEventSlim mre = new ManualResetEventSlim();

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        elapsedtime2++;
        if(elapsedtime2 >= 3)
        {
            mre.Set();
        }
    }
```

If your elapsed time variable has the expected value, you can set the event.

```
mre.Reset();
timer2.Start();
mre.Wait();
timer2.Stop();
```

Before you start the timer, you unset the event. After you started your timer, you wait until the event is set.

Comment: thank you for the answer. It is always great to learn about new "tools". im looking into these